# Calculate MAE in PowerBI - no values error

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am tryning to calculate Mean Absolute Error (MAE) in powerbi (using "new measure" option).

```
MAE_1 =
DIVIDE (
    ABS ( AVERAGE ( 'STATION'[GHI W/sqm] ) - AVERAGE ( 'Forecast_1d'[GHI W/sqm] ) ),
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Forecast_1d' ), 'Forecast_1d'[GHI W/sqm] )
)
```

My data has the following struture (the station data has negative value, while my forecast has 0 values):

| Date | Hour | STATION[GHI W/sqm] | Forecast_1d[GHI W/sqm] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 0:00 | -5.26 | 0 |
| 01/01/2023 | 1:00 | -5.24 | 0 |
| 01/01/2023 | 2:00 | -5.27 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 01/01/2023 | 13:00 | 800 | 789 |
| 01/01/2023 | 14:00 | 799 | 789 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 01/01/2023 | 22:00 | -5.26 | 0 |

However, when I check my results I obtain:

| Date | Hour | STATION[GHI W/sqm] | Forecast_1d[GHI W/sqm] | MAE_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 0:00 | -5.26 | 0 |  |
| 01/01/2023 | 1:00 | -5.24 | 0 |  |
| 01/01/2023 | 2:00 | -5.27 | 0 |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 01/01/2023 | 13:00 | 800 | 789 | 11 |
| 01/01/2023 | 14:00 | 799 | 789 | 10 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 01/01/2023 | 22:00 | -5.26 | 0 |  |

So I am seeing the MAE it has been calculated on positive values in the STATION[GHI W/sqm] column, **but I do not know why I am not calculating the negative values**.

P.D: I have to calculate the average inside the MAE, because the steps of both data are deferents (The station has a step of 5 min while the forecast has a step of 30min). I used a Fact table to relate both tables.

Comment: Please provide the correct DAX for `MAE_1`. The current DAX code is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very strange construct in your `DIVIDE` divisor.

When you specify a formula like this:

```
Foo = 
CALCULATE ( 
   [Measure] , 
   'Table'[Column]
)
```

And your `'Table'[Column]` contains zeroes, you will remove these rows from your calculation altogether, as they will be interpreted by the engine as `FALSE`.

So for all your rows where `Forecast_1d[GHI W/sqm] = 0`, `DIVIDE` will get a blank divisor and will return a blank value. For the rows in your example data where `STATION[GHI W/sqm]` is negative, you also have `Forecast_1d[GHI W/sqm] = 0` which causes your calculation to blank out for these rows.

Comment: What are you saying is correct. First, I have to filter both list and then do the division. However, I do not know the divisor number, so I calculate like this and this solve the problem:
MAE_1 = IF(NOT(ISBLANK(COUNT(STATION[GHI W/sqm]))) && NOT( ISBLANK(COUNT(Forecast_1d[GHI/sqm]))), DIVIDE(ABS(AVERAGE('STATION'[GHI W/sqm]) - AVERAGE('Forecast_1d'[GHI/sqm])), MIN(DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(Forecast_1d[GHI/sqm]), DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(STATION[GHI W/sqm]))))

Change your answer and I will mark it as solved

Comment: Since the root cause of the issue is using the numerical column as a filter, I will just remove the DAX suggestion itself - your DAX code is highly specific to your use-case, whereas the solution to your problem is more of a general nature. I hope you agree!